# SQL Find latest record only if COMPLETE field is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with multiple records submitted by a user. In each record is a field called COMPLETE to indicate if a record is fully completed or not.

I need a way to get the latest records of the user where COMPLETE is 0, LOCATION, DATE are the same and no additional record exist where COMPLETE is 1. In each record there are additional fields such as Type, AMOUNT, Total, etc. These can be different, even though the USER, LOCATION, and DATE are the same.

There is a SUB_DATE field and ID field that denote the day the submission was made and auto incremented ID number. Here is the table:

```
ID  NAME  LOCATION  DATE       COMPLETE  SUB_DATE   TYPE1  AMOUNT1  TYPE2  AMOUNT2  TOTAL
1   user1   loc1    2017-09-15    1      2017-09-10  Food   12.25   Hotel  65.54   77.79
2   user1   loc1    2017-09-15    0      2017-09-11  Food   12.25   NULL      0   12.25
3   user1   loc2    2017-08-13    0      2017-09-05  Flight 140     Food      5   145.00
4   user1   loc2    2017-08-13    0      2017-09-10  Flight 140     NULL      0   140
5   user1   loc3    2017-07-14    0      2017-07-15  Taxi   25      NULL      0   25
6   user1   loc3    2017-08-25    1      2017-08-26  Food   45      NULL      0   45
```

The results I would like is to retrieve are ID 4, because the SUB_DATE is later that ID 3. Which it has the same Name, Location, and Date information and there is no COMPLETE with a 1 value.

I would also like to retrieve ID 5, since it is the latest record for the User, Location, Date, and Complete is 0.

I would also appreciate it if you could explain your answer to help me understand what is happening in the solution.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.  The data and results should be *text* and not an image in the question.

Comment: I suggest taking this one step at a time.  Start by finding the most recent record.

Comment: Where location and date are the same as what?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Edited submission to include SQL Server 2012 tag.

Comment: Can you add what you expect the query output to be for the given data?

Comment: I added which records I would like to retrieve and why.

Comment: sorry,didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood but try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT *,
                    MAX(CONVERT(INT,COMPLETE)) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,LOCATION,DATE) AS CompleteForNameLocationAndDate,
                    MAX(SUB_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, LOCATION, DATE) AS LastSubDate
            FROM    your_table t
        ) a
WHERE   CompleteForNameLocationAndDate = 0 AND
        SUB_DATE = LastSubDate
```

So what we have done here:

First, if you run just the inner query in Management Studio, you will see what that does:

The first max function will partition the data in the table by each unique Name,Location,Date set.
In the case of your data, ID 1 & 2 are the first partition,  3&4 are the second partition, 5 is the 3rd partition and 6 is the 4th partition.
So for each of these partitions it will get the max value in the complete column. Therefore any partition with a 1 as it's max value has been completed.

Note also, the convert function. This is because COMPLETE is of datatype BIT (1 or 0) and the max function does not work with that datatype. We therefore convert to INT. If your COMPLETE column is type INT, you can take the convert out.

The second max function partitions by unique Name, Location and Date again but we are getting the max_sub date this time which give us the date of the latest record for the Name,Location,Date

So we take that query and add it to a derived table which for simplicity we call a. We need to do this because SQL Server doesn't allowed windowed functions in the WHERE clause of queries. A windowed function is one that makes use of the OVER keyword as we have done. In an ideal world, SQL would let us do

```
SELECT *,
       MAX(CONVERT(INT,COMPLETE)) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,LOCATION,DATE) AS CompleteForNameLocationAndDate,
       MAX(SUB_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, LOCATION, DATE) AS LastSubDate
FROM   your)table t
WHERE   MAX(CONVERT(INT,COMPLETE)) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,LOCATION,DATE) = 0 AND
        SUB_DATE = MAX(SUB_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, LOCATION, DATE)
```

But it doesn't allow it so we have to use the derived table.

So then we basically SELECT everything from our derived table Where

```
CompleteForNameLocationAndDate = 0
```

Which are Name,Location, Date partitions which do not have a record marked as complete.

Then we filter further asking for only the latest record for each partition

```
SUB_DATE = LastSubDate
```

Hope that makes sense, not sure what level of detail you need?

As a side, I would look at restructuring your tables (unless of course you have simplified to better explain this problem) as follows:

(Assuming the table in your examples is called Booking)

```
tblBooking
BookingID
PersonID
LocationID
Date
Complete
SubDate

tblPerson
PersonID
PersonName

tblLocation
LocationID
LocationName

tblType
TypeID
TypeName

tblBookingType
BookingTypeID
BookingID
TypeID
Amount
```

This way if you ever want to add Type3 or Type4 to your booking information, you don't need to alter your table layout

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. I'm a bit new to SQL, could you explain what you did for education purposes:)

Comment: also, I would test with some more data to see if does what you want